# Embedding Fonts in AS3 - Dynamic Text Field disappears

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts, embedding

This is hopefully a new problem or just me missing something obvious. Please help! I'm embedding a font into my AS3 application. I'm doing everything by-the-book and it half-works.

In my main class,

```
    [Embed(source="Art/moolbor.ttf", fontFamily="MoolEmbed", 
        mimeType="application/x-font")]
    var MoolEmbed:Class;
```

Then later on in my code:

```
    var newFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    newFormat.font = "MoolEmbed";
    newFormat.size = 20;
    newFormat.color = 0xFCF374;

    year.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    year.text = "Hello World";
    year.embedFonts = true;
    year.setTextFormat(newFormat);
    year.antiAliasType = "advanced";
```

This works perfectly fine, and the text shows up beautifully. I can rotate it, alphas apply to it, and it's nicely antialiased. The problem is that the textfield is dynamic - Later on in the code:

```
    year.text = "And a second hello world";
```

As soon as this code is triggered, the textfield disappears completely. I turn on

```
    year.border = true;
```

and I can see that the textfield is still there, but it's size has shrunk down to just a few pixels. Thinking perhaps it was the autoSize messing things up,

```
    //year.autoSize = ...;
```

Same problems. Thinking it might be embedding, I commented out the line:

```
    //year.embedFonts = true;
```

And the textfield returns to working status, but (Understandably) loses it's ability to do alphas and rotations.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wrote a long talkative entry on possible reasons as why this would not work. But as I re-read you code I think i spotted the error. 
Change the row:

```
year.setTextFormat(newFormat);
```

To:

```
year.defaultTextFormat = newFormat;
```

That should do it!

Comment: Thanks so much! Never used the defaultTextFormat property before... Learn something new every day!

Comment: I have pretty much the same issue, this solution still isn't really working for me.

Fonts.enamurate does show my embedded font.

Comment: thanks, saved me allot of work. However, in my case I had to add instead of change.

Comment: Ten Years later, still this is a helpful post. I followed the same instructions here, but it setting the font to antialiasing was what it made it work for me. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

as defaultTextFormat didnt work for, a combination of the other two tips worked

```
import flash.text.Font;
```

in your constructor:

```
Font.registerFont(MoolEmbed)
```

and then

After you set the text property for the second time make sure you call setTextFormat(newFormat) again.

Answer (score 0):

you need to register your font with the global font list.

import:

```
import flash.text.Font;
```

in your constructor:

```
Font.registerFont(MoolEmbed)
```

Answer (score 0):

After you set the text property for the second time make sure you call setTextFormat(newFormat) again.